# Alternate row colours with grouping in RDLC

Tags: report, rdlc

I need to create alternate row colours in my RDLC report which also takes into account groups.

If I use the expression

```
=Iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2, "PaleGreen", "White")
```

Obviously this creates problems when groups are used.  I've not had much luck finding information so any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this topic was brought up ages ago, but in case somebody has a similar issue (like I did) and runs into this thread, here is how I tackled it.  Here is an example of the report grouping and sample results in my report:

Group 1
   Sub 1
   Sub 2
   Sub 3

Group 2
   Sub 1
   Sub 2
   Sub 3

Notice that 'Sub [1-3]' are the exact same header.  When using (Fields!GroupId.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing), the statement determines that there are only 3 unique values, and when it gets to the repeating subgroups (Sub [1-3]), the result of the RunningValue does not increase.

You can test this out by putting an extra column in your report and then the expression: (RunningValue(Fields!GroupId.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing).  The results would look like this:

Group 1
   Sub 1   **1**
   Sub 2   **2**
   Sub 3   **3**

Group 2
   Sub 1   **3**
   Sub 2   **3**
   Sub 3   **3**

Because the values start repeating, the 'mod 2' portion of the alternating row logic gets messed up.  To work around this I had the RunningValue statement combine the Group header as well as the Sub group:

(RunningValue(Fields!GroupId.Value+Fields!SubGroupId.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing)

After I did this I got this result:

Group 1
   Sub 1   **1**
   Sub 2   **2**
   Sub 3   **3**

Group 2
   Sub 1   **4**
   Sub 2   **5**
   Sub 3   **6**

Throw that in to your alternating row expression and it should work!

Comment: Ah, a simple but useful technique. I'll start implementing this myself!

Answer (score 13):

Decided to go with the following code I found online:

```
=IIf(RunningValue(Fields!GroupId.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2, "White", "#d6f1fc")
```

It doesnt alternate every row colour but keeps all the rows in that group the same colour which make the report nice and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

use this: =iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, true,false)